# Are images taken by launching a camera intent saved to cache?

Tags: java, android

From the `onActivityResult(...) {...}` I can get the path to the image taken by launching a camera intent with `data.getData()`. Is this a cache location or a persistent location? I can't find any documentation on it?

I am going to pass it to the server, but I don't know if I have to delete the image or if I have to copy it another location before doing further things with it?

Answer (score 2):

Good question, I suspect that this might not be the same over all devices and versions. In my experience if you do not specify a location to save the image it saves it to the default camera photos folder, so it does persist (in addition you get back a small bitmap through the onActivityResult). But I am not sure about other devices.

The camera intent has a few inconsistencies overall for example: The size of the bitmap you get back from the camera varies slightly, most devices will save the image in its correct orientation, however some devices (namely a few Samsung devices) will always save the file itself in the same way but will store the proper information inside the EXIF, also on some devices/versions the activity that calls the camera intent will always get destroyed and re-created once the camera is finished regardless of any other factor.

So it might not be something that is universal.